# Resizing UITextView issue

Tags: swift, uitextview

I am aware people have asked this question before, but looking at their code and etc... it is little different compared to mine.

I am trying to resize my UITextView depending on the size of the content. On the IPhone 6 and 6 Plus the code works fine.

However, on iPhone 4s and 5, in portrait mode, it cuts off some of the content, but in landscape it appears again.

this is the code that i have added for the height to resize:

```
let fixedWidth = DetailsViewer.frame.size.width
    DetailsViewer.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = DetailsViewer.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = DetailsViewer.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    DetailsViewer.frame = newFrame
    heightConstraint.constant = newFrame.height
```

If anyone could help this issue, i would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this works with UIWebViews with the following code.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1
    webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
}
```

The equivalent would be the following: (resizing editing ended, you can use any other method too depending on what you want to do)

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    textView.frame.size.height = 1
    textView.frame.size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
}
```

Remember to import and set the delegate before:

```
class myClass: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    /*your code*/

    myTextView.delegate = self
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. i needed to move the entire block of code into an viewDidAppear instead of having it at viewWillAppear

let fixedWidth = DetailsViewer.frame.size.width
    DetailsViewer.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = DetailsViewer.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = DetailsViewer.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    DetailsViewer.frame = newFrame
    heightConstraint.constant = newFrame.height